# BufferedWriter doesn't throw any error, but file is blank

Tags: java, file-io

I'm brand new to using Java for web servers, and I'm writing a very basic application that writes micro-posts to a file, which will later be called and displayed. ( I know a database would be better for this, but this is for an assignment and we are using file-I/O to keep things simple.)

Here is the method in my servlet that receives the form post and writes data to my file:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String content = request.getParameter("postContent");

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); 
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; //add one because the Calendar class numbers months 0-11
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    String dateTime = Integer.toString(month) + "/" + Integer.toString(day) + "/" + Integer.toString(year) + " " + Integer.toString(hour) + ":" + Integer.toString(minutes); 

    String user = request.getSession().getAttribute("username").toString();

    ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();    
    String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/posts.txt");
    //String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/posts.txt");

    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));
        writer.write(user);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(dateTime);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(content);
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    response.sendRedirect("listPosts.jsp");
}
```

When I run the application, everthing goes smoothly and I end up redirected to `listPost.jsp`, but my file is blank. I've looked at other questions but I'm doing everything everything right that I know of. Am I setting up the BufferedWriter wrong? Could I have posts.txt in the wrong place? (it is in the WebContent folder).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
The value of the `path` variable is as follows:
    `/home/[myusername]/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/forum/posts.txt`

**UPDATE**
I now know that I can read from `posts.txt`, so this tells me that the application is not having trouble finding it.

I'm reading from the file with the following code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("posts.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String username = reader.readLine();
    String dateTime = reader.readLine();
    String postContent = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();

    request.setAttribute("username", username);
    request.setAttribute("dateTime", dateTime);
    request.setAttribute("postContent", postContent);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/listPosts.jsp").forward(request, response);;
}
```

Comment: Is this any Exception occurring when you tried to write or open the file.

Comment: @FrankZHENG No, No errors at all.

Comment: I have a doubt that are you are checking the file in correct location? File will be created in the project where the java class resides. There is no wrong in your code. Double check the location of the file you are creating.

Comment: can you tell what value path variable has?

Comment: @Jayaprasad see the update on my question

Comment: @Jayaprasad I have another file in the same location that I can read from perfectly

Comment: I see that your method does not handle `IOException`s. It is possible that your creation of a `FileWriter` threw a `FileNotFoundException`. Check the log file for messages, and show us that you have done so.

Comment: @Raedwald, See my updated code to see the exception handling. No output, I don't think any exception was thrown.

Comment: @EJP is there anything else I can do to check for exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I feel pretty foolish now. It was working all along but it was writing and reading from a file in the directory of the server, not where my source code is stored. So when I checked the text file I had manually created, it showed no change because it was not the file being used. Thanks for everyone for your help and input, sorry about wasting your time.